# How to split strings in an array into arrays of characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I'm making a simple program that jumbles up the letters in words. I want to split every word into an array, within the existing one. i.e.

```
    ['hello','my','name','is','Anders']

    [['h','e','l,'l','o'],['m','y'],['n','a','m','e'],['i','s'],['A','n','d','e','r','s']
```

So how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Split all members with empty character.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you not know how to transform an array by transforming each element? Do you not know how to split a string into its component characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```js
var arr = ['hello','my','name','is','Anders', ''];
var res = arr.map(e => e.split(""));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and take single characters.

```js
var array = ['hello','my','name','is','Anders', ''],
    splitted = array.map(s => [...s]);
    
console.log(splitted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Array.map* function and the *String.split*, so your code would be like this:

```
phrase = ['hello','my','name','is','Anders']
phrase.map(x => x.split(""))
```

Comment: Can you give an example where this code could fail?

Comment: Any supplementary-plane character such as .